# Strange Activity with TexStudio after Installing Package

Tags: errors, packages

I'm writing a program in TexStudio which includes an algorithm/pseudocode.

I used the [second post here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/96587/algorithm-with-latex-package-algorithmicx) to help write the pseudocode.

After installing the following packages:

```
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
```

it runs find and builds the document and looks great, but I'm getting the following `messages` in the command and it keeps flashing up the first page of the document in the center of the scene (for less than a second).

```
Process started: pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode "template".te
Process exited normally
Process started: latex -interaction=nonstopmode "ZP7332".tex
Process started: latex -interaction=nonstopmode "HS7332".tex
Process exited with error(s)
Process started: dvipng.exe -T tight -D 120 "ZP7332".dvi
Process exited with error(s)
Process started: dvipng.exe -T tight -D 120 "HS7332".dvi
Process exited normally
Process exited normally
Process started: latex -interaction=nonstopmode "lK7332".tex
Process exited with error(s)
Process started: dvipng.exe -T tight -D 120 "lK7332".dvi
Process exited normally
```

Would it be best to avoid these packages or can I fix this issue and stop the flashing and error messages?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Is this an issue of TeX Studio or rather an issue of the underlying LaTeX run? Try to compile the file from the commandline and see what pdflatex/latex spits out as message.

Comment: I think its a TeXStudio-Error for the Error occurred only if TXS compiles the preview.
the whole Document compiles without Error